# database - how do I make sure that a new change in computation rates will only affect new records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a table that contains records of student grades that is grouped with an id created with a class record table.

It has three grading components, written works, perfomance tasks, and quarterly examination, each with their own component weight depending on the subject type (example, one subject type may have written works as 25% of final grade and performance task 45% and quarterly exams 30%)

However, those component weights may change and here comes what I want to do.

How can I make sure that the new component weight will only affect newly created class records (created next schoolyear and so.), and that old class records will stick to the component weight that was active at the time it was created.

Here is what the tables look like, (the column name is not that long but I just use the complete word in order to be much more understandable)

```
            classrecord
            -ClassID
            -SubjectID
            -SchoolyearID
            -MaxWrittenWorksGrade
            -MaxPerformanceTaskGrade
            -MaxQuarterlyExaminationGrade

            grades
            -RecordID
            -StudentID
            -ClassID
            -WrittenWorksGrade
            -PerformanceTaskGrade
            -QuarterlyExaminationGrade
            -FinalGrade

            subjects
            -SubjectID
            -SubjectName
            -SubjectTypeID

            subjecttype
            -SubjectTypeID
            -SubjectTypeName
            -SubjectTypeWeightID

            subjtypeweight
            -SubjectTypeWeightID
            -WrittenWorksWeight
            -PerformanceTaskWeight
            -QuarterlyExaminationWeight
```

As you can see here that during computations the table subjtypeweight is referenced via classrecord > subject > subjtype > subjtypeweight

I am only a student and the design that I came up with may be problematic but I appreciate any feed backs were to be given to improve this.

Thank you very much for bearing with me, I find it hard explaining what I ask so please just ask me if there is anything confusing or missing in my question thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic time-based data problem.

It looks like your `subjtypeweight` table contains rows that have a beginning and end effective date. Perhaps each row of that table is in effect for just one year. Then, you can add a `SchoolyearID` column to that table, and make the table's primary key into a compound of `SubjectTypeWeightID, SchoolyearID`. Then, use a query containing a series of `JOINs` like this.

```
 FROM classrecord c
 JOIN subjects s ON c.ClassID = s.ClassID
 JOIN subjecttype st ON s.SubjectTypeID = st.SubjectTypeID
 JOIN subjtypeweight stw ON st.SubjectTypeWeightID = stw.SubjectTypeWeightID
                        AND c.SchoolyearID = stw.SchoolyearID
```

Notice the two parts of the last `ON` clause, joined by `AND`.  They'll pull the correct row from your `subjtypeweight` table.

You'll need to INSERT new subjtypeweight rows for each new school year to use this approach.  You could get out of having to do that every year by adding, not one, but two columns to `subjtypeweight`: `SchoolyearID` and `LastSchoolyearID`.  Allow `LastSchoolyearId` to contain null values. Then use this in your query.

```
 FROM classrecord c
 JOIN subjects s ON c.ClassID = s.ClassID
 JOIN subjecttype st ON s.SubjectTypeID = st.SubjectTypeID
 JOIN subjtypeweight stw 
         ON st.SubjectTypeWeightID = stw.SubjectTypeWeightID
        AND c.SchoolyearID >= stw.SchoolyearID
        AND (stw.LastSchoolyearID IS NULL OR c.SchoolyearID <= stw.LastSchoolyearID)
```

That's a complex `ON` clause. But it serves the purpose of selecting the correct row from the `subjtypeweight` column based on its first and last year (if any) of validity.

If you want to update your weighting, UPDATE the existing row to "retire" it by showing the last school year for which it is valid. Then INSERT a new row showing the first year for which it is valid. (Don't let your effective years overlap or your `JOIN` operations will produce too many records.)

Don't worry about performance. SQL is made for this stuff.

I learned this by reading Prof. Richard Snodgrass's book on Developing Time Based Applications in SQL. Dr. Snodgrass has generoously made it available in PDF form. https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html

Comment: If you're using `DATE` values for `DateEffective` and `DateRetired`, you also need a `DATE` value for each class. You didn't show that; instead you showed a `SchoolyearID`. I made the assumption that it has values like `2016` and '2017`.

Comment: Yes, I assigned an id that belongs to a `schoolyear` table which has a `startdate` and an `enddate` column